# SQL select data from multiple tables sorted by a column within each category

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
table1                                      table2
----------------------------               --------------------------------
sym        i_date    value                 id (PK)    sym         mapping
----------------------------               --------------------------------
abc       2017-2-23    3.4                      1         abc         MP1
xyz       2013-1-12    4.5                      2         xyz         MP3  
def       2011-1-1     1.1                      3         def         MP1
abc       2012-1-23    3.2
```

For a given 'mapping' value i want to retrieve all sym that match the mapping and then retrieve all i_date and values with all i_dates sorted in ascending order for each sym.

For e.g, if i specify 'MP1' i want to retrieve it like this:

```
Expected Result
----------------------------              
sym        i_date    value                
----------------------------              
abc       2012-1-23    3.2         
abc       2017-2-23    3.4                                             
def       2011-1-1     1.1
```

I'm able to get the data without the sorting for each sym with the following sql statement:

```
select table1.sym,
    table1.i_date,
    table1.value
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.sym = table2.sym
where table2.mapping = 'MP1'
```

Please advise on how i can get the expected result (show below). Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried simple `order by table1.sym` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here, a simple `order by` should do it:

```
select table1.sym,
    table1.i_date,
    table1.value
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.sym = table2.sym
where table2.mapping = 'MP1'
order by table1.sym, table1.i_date
```

Comment: sigh. Thank you. I had tried "order by table1.i_date" without ordering first by table1.sym and wasn't getting the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select table1.sym,
table1.i_date,
table1.value
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.sym = table2.sym
 where table2.mapping = 'MP1'
 order by table1.sym,
table1.i_date
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you just need something simple like the ordering clause?

select table1.sym,
    table1.i_date,
    table1.value
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.sym = table2.sym
where table2.mapping = 'MP1'e
order by table2.mapping, table1.value

You need to use the order by clause. Ir first order by the first element specified, then by the second

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query.

```
select table1.sym,
    table1.i_date,
    table1.value
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.sym = table2.sym
where table2.mapping = 'MP1' order by table1.i_date ,table1.sym
```

Comment: thanks. i used "order by table1.sym, table1.i_date" to get the result